# drop down list onclick change value of input not working on chrome or opera

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, opera

i have drop down item list. when i select an item. it should update input box on item prices.
but it works perfectly on firefox and IE 9. dont work chrome or opera. anybody have an idea ?

```
<option onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('price').value='$0.00'"/>   


<input type="text" name="price" id="price" />
```

Comment: Do you have any example code to share? Do you also handle 'onchange'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These `<option>` elements in your code should be wrapped in a `<select>` element. When the selection changes, it results in a change event getting triggered. You should update the UI by handling the change event (rather than a click on a particular element). You should probably also factor out your handler function into an external JavaScript file (and put it into a named function) rather than defining the handler inline in the HTML file as you are doing with this piece of example code.